# Adding side captions to new floattype only?

Tags: floats, captions

I'm writing a document with several types of floats. **Only** for equations, I want the caption to be aligned with the right side of the page and the first line of the equation (requirement by my university).
Here is what I've come up with so far, but it just doesn't do anything to format of the captions for my equations, they still are formatted like the captions for figures, tables etc.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[raggedright]{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{equation}{H}{equt}[chapter]
\floatname{equation}{Equation}
\sidecaptionvpos{equation}{t}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{equation}
\[ \tilde{x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} x^2 (t) dt} \]
\caption{RMS value}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: An example how it should look in a finished document:
[image: Example]

In the end, equations have to be formatted precisely as shown, so there's more to it. The side caption should only include the number (chapter.counter), but I'm trying to solve this riddle step-by-step.

Comment: `sidecap`  provides captions beside the figures or tables with environments `SCfigure` and `SCtable`. It does not change the captions of floats without these environments. AFAIK is does not provide a user interface to define new such environments. Maybe such environments can be implemented by copy&modify of the definition of `SCfigure` or `SCtable`. Maybe using another package like [`hvfloat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) would be easier. But with `\[…\]`, I guess you would have to limit the width manually. Maybe the tag mechanism of `amsmath` can be used for a short caption.

Comment: Maybe it would help, if you'd show a sketch of the expected result, not only for very small captions but also for longer captions.

Comment: @cabohah Good idea! I provided an example in the original question. Longer captions are not an issue, as only the number is to be printed (which is not yet represented in my MWE, as I haven't figured this out yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally equations are centered.  Using indentation is possible, but more difficult.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\mathindent}% for convenience
\setlength{\mathindent}{\bibindent}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\begin{flalign}
\hspace{\mathindent}& \tilde{x} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} x^2 (t) dt} &\\
  &\hspace{\mathindent} \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{% width approximate
  mit\\
  $x(t)$: Ausgangsgr\"o\ss e}&\notag
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to do the trick!